# php select query using parameter from previous page

Tags: php, mysql, sql, methods, get

I wanted to query something from the database but it does not return any values at all. I wondered why when it does not reported any error.Kindly check attachment.

[image]

Here is the code i made.Thank you.

```
echo '<form method = "post" action = "http://localhost:8080/nbm/delivery/show_delivery_details.php">';

$nbm = new Db();

$poid = $_GET['id'];// this was taken from the previous page
echo $poid;//tried to display this and it does

 $get_deliveries= $nbm->query("SELECT * FROM `customer_order_list` where purchase_order_id = '$poid'");

    foreach($get_deliveries as $key){
     echo $key['purchase_order_id'].'&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$key['customer_id'].'&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$key['amount'];

   }

print_r($get_deliveries);//also tried this but it displays nothing

echo '</form>';
```

Comment: @Count Dracula: If there is no errors displaying, try to print last executed query and check whether it is as you expected. You can use mysqli_info() for that.

Comment: use `var_dump` instead of `print_r` and see the result, most likely the query returns no results. You should also try to query the database directly using something like PHPMyAdmin or the console

Comment: you can even write the query like "SELECT * FROM `customer_order_list` where purchase_order_id = ".$poid if you are taking care of prepare statements...

Comment: @Count Dracula: Have you got the solution?

Comment: No, not yet. **JTheDev**.

Comment: how about the 'last query executed'?

Comment: I also tried that, I even tried to make a different query on the same page-it works as expected, I edited the query of my posted question- I removed the where clause, it returns the exact values. Is the problem is in $poid?How come when $poid contains the correct value, I even echoed $poid.@**JTheDev**

Comment: can you please post the query?

Comment: I tried this and it works as expected $get_deliveries= $nbm->query("SELECT * FROM `customer_order`"); but when i add a where clause  $get_deliveries= $new_batch_marketing->query("SELECT * FROM `customer_order` where `purchase_order_id` = '$poid'"); it displays nothing...as what my posted question shows. **JTheDev**.

Comment: Not this, after the query, you can write a mysqli_info(connection); function to display the last executed query. So that you can find if there is any logical mistakes in the query. This is what we are doing to find logical mistakes. more info: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_info.asp

Comment: I wonder if you have any idea about this - I tried to compare $poid from the value returned from the query- if($key['purchase_order_id'] == $poid){echo "match";}else{echo"mismatch";}. It is expected that $poid will have an exactly the same value from the query result but sadly it returns mismatch.What does it mean, is somethings wrong with the $poid?@**JTheDev**

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because `$_GET` data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: @CountDracula: If the result of the query is empty, as you told before, how can you compare something with that? First of all, try to figure out the query is correct or not. Then find the results, then do this comparison. I strongly believe the query is having logical mistakes if you are not getting any result, even though there are matching rows.

Comment: @CountDracula: Maybe it is related your DB class.

Comment: I am certain with that because I know the entries of the table where the query is directed. Anyways I have just solved it, the problem is with the $_GET['poid']-it contains spaces which is a NO NO, that is why it does not mach with any entry in the database. Thank you very much **Mr. JTheDev**.

Comment: @CountDracula: glad to hear that you've solved the issue.

Comment: Thank you, hope I can hear you in my future questions.@**JTheDev**

Answer (score 1):

```
  $nbm->query("SELECT * FROM `customer_order_list` where purchase_order_id = '".$poid."'");
```

Comment: I have also tried that. Thank you though **Mr. Midhun k**.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$nbm = new Db();

$poid = $_GET['id'];
$get_deliveries= $nbm->query("SELECT * FROM `customer_order_list` where purchase_order_id = '$poid'");

echo '<form method = "post" action = "show_delivery_details.php">';

    foreach($get_deliveries as $key){
     echo $key['purchase_order_id'].'&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$key['customer_id'].'&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$key['amount'];

   }

echo '</form>';
```

?>

Try to print a $key variable inside foreach loop . instead of print_r use var_dump($var);

Comment: I tried your answer but it is still the same, and also var_dump only returns array(0) { }. Thank you though @ **Kamlesh Gupta**.

Answer (score 0):

Execute your query first with your get $poid value in db directly.

```
SELECT * FROM `customer_order_list` where purchase_order_id = '$poid'
```

Then after $res=$nbm->query(SELECT * FROM `customer_order_list` where purchase_order_id = '$poid'). you want to fetch the result.

```
mysql_fetch_result($res);
```

check whether you u did this.